Perturbation of one-parameter groups of unitary operators
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $h$ be a fixed,  densely defined, possibly unbounded, self-adjoint operator on $H$.  Letting $B(H)$ denote the space of all bounded operators on $H$, it is well known that the map
$$
  t\in {\mathbb R}\mapsto e^{ith}\in B(H),
  $$
is continuous when $B(H)$ is equipped with the strong operator topology.  Moreover, this map is continuous relative to the norm topology on $B(H)$ if and only if $h$ is a bounded operator.
Suppose now that $b$ is a bounded, self-adjoint operator on $H$ which commutes with the operator $h$ fixed above (in the sense that $b$ leaves the domain of $h$ invariant and commutes with all spectral projections of $h$), and let $k=h+b$.  Then
$$
  e^{itk}= e^{ith}e^{itb},\quad \forall t\in {\mathbb R},
  $$
whence the map
$$
  t\mapsto e^{-ith}e^{itk}=e^{itb}
  $$
is norm continuous.
My question has to do with the converse of the above fact.  Precisely, suppose that we are given two densely defined, possibly unbounded, self-adjoint operators $h$ and $k$ on $H$, such that the map
$$
  t\mapsto e^{-ith}e^{itk}
  $$
is norm continuous.  What can we then say about $h$ and $k$?

The converse is of course not true (not sure if this is really what you are asking). For example, $h,k$ could both be orthogonal sums of operators on $H=H_1\oplus H_2$, with $h_1,k_1$ bounded but not commuting and $h_2=k_2$ unbounded.

@ChristianRemling, thanks for your comment.  Indeed I was not expecting a literal converse as your example clearly shows this not to be true.  The preamble of my question should be taken as just exhibiting an example in which you get norm continuity of $e^{-ith}e^{itk}$.   The precise question, though, is what info on $h$ and $k$ do you get from this continuity, which is of course not automatic.
